# Grails creating routines

Tags: grails, routines

Let's say, i have a specific information in the database that needs to be sent for a specific user by email in a specific time of the day.

a) How can i create a routine in Grails, which is basically an action that is always running - without being associated with any event? Let's say, every hour that action is runned.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
while(true){

...
myCodeHere
...
wait 30minutes
}
```

Will this actually work? Without too much processing? And how can i have an action permanently running no matter what. I there is a specific way of doing this?
Thanks in advanced,
RR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding quartz and plugins you may use pure Spring Framework

1) add to container

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

(do not forget to define task and tx namespaces)

2) Create some bean and add method

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=4000)
public void method() {
  // do something every 4 seconds
}
```

finish!
For more info see [spring framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this in a grails app is with the [Quartz scheduler plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz).  The plugin provides a simple cron-like DSL for scheduling jobs.  For example, to run a job every 30 minutes, you could configure it like this:

```
class MyJob  {
    static cronExpression = "0 0/30 * * * ?"

    def execute(){ /* do something useful */ }
}
```

If you want to run a background thread all the time, take a look at the [executor plugin](https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor) which provides an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) wrapped up properly to get a hibernate session.